# Set Cookies from ExpressJS backend response

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, express-session

We have a frontend (`ExpressJS app`) on http://localhost:4000 and a backend (`Serverless Framework + ExpressJS`) on http://localhost:3000.

I am trying to set session cookies on backend, but cookies are not exist on client (browser).

**Backend**

```
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(sessions({
  secret: "...",
  saveUninitialized:true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, domain: 'localhost:4000', secure: false, httpOnly: true },
  resave: false,
  store: new redisStore({ host: '__REDIS_URL__', port: 6379, client: client,ttl : 260}),
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,UPDATE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, Set-Cookie');
  next();
});

app.post('/user/login', async (_, res) => {
  const out = await Login({
    email: _.body.email,
    password: _.body.password,
  });

  if (out.userId !== -1) {
    _.session.userId = out.userId;
    _.session.marketId = out.marketId;
  }
  res.json(out);
});
```

When I request to this backend API via Postman, cookies are perfectly set. When I try to request this API from Express frontend with axios:

**Frontend**

```
router.post('/login', async function (req, res, next) {
    const body = req.body

    try {
        const resp = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/dev/user/login", {
            email: body.email,
            password: body.password
        }, {withCredentials: true})
        
        /*
          At this point, `resp.headers` exist with correct cookie information.
        */

        if (resp.data.marketId !== -1 && resp.data.userId !== -1) {
            // This HTTP request will fail 401 Unauthorized because of missing cookies
            const photos = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/dev/user/photos", {
            }, {withCredentials: true})
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/login?failed=true')
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
});
```

The variable `resp` contains headers as expected but these cookies are not set on the browser. even if I use `{withCredentials: true}`, Axios is not setting up cookies.

Comment: There are a few possible causes. Can you confirm your client and server are served from the same Domain? Browsers only show cookies from the same Domain. Also, your cookie could be set as 'HttpOnly'. Can you share the code which sets the cookie in your app? - Alternatively you can check the 'ResponseHeaders' in your browser dev-tools for the login request. There should be a 'Set-Cookie' header. If that one is missing, add an additional Cors header in your app: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Set-Cookie`. Let me know if these work

Comment: Hello @MarcRo, be and fe are both served from localhost but different ports. `node-session` handling cookie creation for me. Also 'Set-Cookie' allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Comment: I assume node-session sets httpOnly cookies. Why do you need to read the session cookie? I'm not sure it is secure to make this cookie available to third party JS (which cookies inside dociment.cookie are). Maybe what you're trying to do can be solved in a different way

Comment: What I am trying to do is a session management (authenticating users)

Comment: @MarcRo I have updated the code snippet of **Frontend** . Please see the `if() statement`. What I am doing is basic authentication. I am sending user credentials to backend and if credentials are correct backend is generating a cookie with session id. I need this session id for consecutive API requests so backend will know that the user is authenticated and with help of the session id I am able to get user id information on the backend

Comment: In this case you don't need to access the cookie on your client. Only your server needs to read the session cookie to associate the request with the corresponding session. Try making another request to your backend (with withCredentials: true ) and read the cookie on server side.

Comment: @MarcRo , this is the issue. I am doing exactly what you are saying. But when I make another request to backend, backend is thinking this is a new session (because frontend not sending the cookie) and generating a new session with new session data. It's ignoring the first session created during login.

Comment: Can you check whether the response header contains a set-cookie header? You can see this in the network tab of the browser dev tools

Comment: Yes there is a set-cookie header. But I'm not sending the request with ajax, as you see in my `frontend` code snippet I am sending request from node server of frontend @MarcRo

Comment: I missunderstood your question sorry. I assumed you were using a front-end in the actual sense (a user-facing client). Node-servers don't automatically set cookies for you. You have to set the cookies in your outgoing axios request to "http://localhost:3000/dev/user/photos". Something along `axios.get(url, { headers: { Cookie: <Cookies> } })`. As far as I know don't need `withCredentials` because CORS only exist for Web-Browsers.